# Discussion about a new nuclear fusion design

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

this company is running a similar project described below.
https://firstlightfusion.com/technology/#our-approach
Let me clarify here, this is not cold fusion. D&T gas will be compressed very rapidly and its temperature will increase very fast. So, I don't think this is a duplicate question.

I have a new nuclear fusion design. As below picture.
[image]

This idea is very simple. By accelerating piston (right side) toward the cylinder, we can very easily accelerate piston to speed 100 kilometers per second or higher. The piston will compress D&T mixed gas, and gas will ignite before the cylinder falls to pieces. The cylinder, at this time, you can treat it as a pure fusion bomb. If we put this fusion bomb to a cave and then collect the energy of this bomb and produce electric power.
By simply extender accelerating RAIL or improve piston weight, we can easily make the piston with very high kinetic energy to compress D&T gas.

Comment: Sorry, that's nowhere near enough pressure. See the linked question.

Comment: No, man, my solution is different from "Nuclear Fusion with extremely...", because the mixed gas will be compressed very fast and its temperature will be increased rapidly as well. The fusion process will happen under high pressure and temperature. This is a unique feature. And this ignition process is totally same as typical second stage of hydrogen-bomb explosive.

Comment: I'm sceptical. Please add your pressure and temperature calculations to your question. And if the temperature is supposed to be high, why did you add the cold-fusion tag?

Comment: Sorry, Buddy, I made a mistake. I already remove "cold fusion tag". I am not capable to provide calculations. But, the whole ignition process is exactly similar to hydrogen-bomb. I assume you know how hydrogen-bomb works. In the second stage of hydrogen-bomb, x-ray emitted by fission will heat the container of D&T gas, then the shell of the container will explode and squeeze D&T gas. My solution just repeats the same process of stage 2. And please be aware of the piston speed, it possibly reaches more than 100 kilometers per second.

Comment: A piston travelling at 100 km/s? What type of container do you propose to prevent it from being destroyed on impact?

Comment: Hi, hdhondt, you can consider the cylinder is a shell of pure fusion bomb. You don't need to worry the container be destroyed.

Comment: The point of the answer to the linked question is that fusion from simple mechanical compression requires a ridiculously high pressure, and you'll never achieve that from your railgun compressor. To get fusion you also need high temperature, and even though the gas will heat up when it's compressed mechanically it won't get hot enough. You *can* do fusion at low pressure and high temperature in a [fusor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusor), which uses electrical acceleration to achieve the high temperature, but fusors (currently) consume more energy than the usable energy they output.

Comment: Oh, I realize what's wrong with my design. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Note that this is not a new idea: it is, in its basic concept, similar to General Fusion's concept, where you have a plasma in the center of a sphere, surrounded by a liquid metal vortex. Pistons bang synchonizly onto this liquid metal, generating sound waves. Those sound waves should met the center, resulting in a compression and thus driving the plasma to fusion conditions.

Comment: I see, maybe I should learn more information from General Fusion's website. Thank you, buddy!

Comment: But I have one more question, why National Ignition Facility tries to use 192 laser beams generate X-RAY then by using X-RAY to squeeze fusion capsule. There is any source can heat fusion capsule. Do they want to use X-RAY to heat and squeeze capsule at the same time?

Comment: "is exactly similar to hydrogen-bomb" - it is not. A hydrogen bomb is ignited by radiation implosion, a process that takes place nearly at the speed of light. That's 3000x faster than your piston. Moreover, it's cylindreical so you get far higher compression in the core. NIF's implosions are at about 350 km/s, but spherical, and they're not fast enough as it turns out. I don't think you can offer a system that will drive a piston to the ~10% speed of light this would need for linear compression.

Comment: As to the question about how NIF works - the heat is mostly just compression, but there are plasma interactions and hot electrons driven into the fuel as well.

Comment: a similar idea like mine. https://www.nextbigfuture.com/2022/04/first-light-fusion.html